# Segmentation Fault in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtGui.so.4 when using ROS packages cv_bridge and image_transport on Raspberry PI 3

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ros

I face problems when **running example ROS code** on Raspberry PI 3 when **adding dependencies cv_bridge and image_transport** to my own package. I took the code from the example publisher and subscriber tutorial which can be found in [Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29).

Since I want to grab images and send them to another node, I use cv_bridge and image_transport. I only adapted the package.xml and CMakeLists.txt. **The C++ code is left unchanged**.

When starting image_talker on the Raspberry PI 3 the program stopps with segmentation fault. **When I run the same code on a Desktop PC it runs flawlessly**. The Desktop PC runs Ubuntu 16 LTS with ROS Kinetic installed from the official ROS repositories.

The backtrace from gdb is given below.

```
(gdb) r Starting program: /home/pi/my_workspace
/devel/lib/image_beginner_tutorials/image_talker
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled] 
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-
gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1". 
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction. 
0x6b57ede8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-
gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 
(gdb) c Continuing. 
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x6c966678 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-
gnueabihf/libQtGui.so.4 
(gdb) bt
#0 0x6c966678 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-
gnueabihf/libQtGui.so.4
#1 0x76fdeffc in call_init (l=<optimized out="">, 
argc=1, argv=0x7efff044, env=0x7efff04c) at dl-init.c:78
#2 0x0000021c in ?? () Backtrace stopped: previous 
frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

According to some googling, it seems like `libopenssl` intentionally fires `SIGILL`. After continuing the program execution, it stops with a segmentation fault.

The system I use is Raspbian Jessi with a customly built ROS Kinetic. Building ROS was done according to [Installing ROS Kinetic on the Raspberry Pi](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi).

### Update

After digging deeper into the problem, it seems like the executables link for some reason against two different versions of Qt. It seems like ROS Kinetic makes use of a mixture of Qt5 and Qt4 libraries, according to [ROS Kinetic Migration Guide](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Migration). This causes problems on certain sytems like on the Raspberry PI 3 with Rasbpian Jessi as it seems.

The ldd output is given below.

```
ldd image_talker  | grep Qt
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x7402f000)
    libQt5Test.so.5 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Test.so.5 (0x73ff9000)
    libQt5Concurrent.so.5 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Concurrent.so.5 (0x73fe4000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x73c14000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x7378f000)
    libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtGui.so.4 (0x6c533000)
    libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtCore.so.4 (0x6c292000)
```

I tried out some of the hints given in the [ROS Kinetic Migration Guide](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Migration), but they did not solve the problem. I tried to use only parts of OpenCV, namely `core`, in `CMakeLists.txt`. Setting up a ROS Kinetic variant which has no GUI dependencies is also not possible, since cv_bridge and image_transport are not shipped then.